# Measure width and height for a custom view which draw text in the canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I  have an custom view which will draw the text in the canvas accordingly:

```
public class MTextView extends View {
    public String fontFamily = "default";
    public float fontSize = 14;
    public String text = "Hello";
    public int fontFillColor;



    private Paint textPaint = new Paint();

    private Rect bound = new Rect();

    public MTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (text == null || text.equals("")) return;


        textPaint.setColor(fontFillColor);
        textPaint.setTextSize(fontSize);
        textPaint.setTypeface(getTypeFace());
        canvas.drawText(text, 10, 60, textPaint);

        textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length() - 1, bound);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(bound.width(), bound.height());
        Log.d("view", bound + "");
    }
}
```

Now once I add this view to the layout, I can not see this view, and I always get the log like:

```
view Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)
```

It seems that the `onMeasure` does not get the real dimension.

How to fix it?

Comment: onMeasure is called before onDraw

Comment: Any alternative solution?

Comment: you simply call setMeasuredDimension with two zeros as width and height,  change it to return values you think are correct

Comment: I do not know the dimension of the view, since it should be calculated by the text drawed in the canvas, that's why I call `bound.width()`.

Comment: so call textPaint.getTextBounds in onMeasure

Comment: hey do you ever got your answer for this ? I am in the same problem !!